# Any ideas on why this python code returns a 500 internal server error?

Tags: python, html

I have multiple .py files in my project, and none of them do this except for my survey.py. Basically, survey.py is given information from an html form, and I need to display the results. I did this by appending the value of the answers to the survey to a .txt file. 
This works fine without any code, and the information gets appended, however, when I try to write the html I am given a 500 internal server error. I've looked at the code for a while and I can't find any mistakes.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
page = 'Content-type: text/html\n\n'
one = open('1.txt', 'a')
two = open('2.txt', 'a')
three = open('3.txt', 'a')

one.write(form.getvalue('play'))
two.write(form.getvalue('instrument'))
three.write(form.getvalue('type'))
```

When I tried just this, i noticed that the information gets appended, but when I tried displaying it in html with something like this:

```
a = open('1.txt', 'r')
b = open('2.txt', 'r')
c = open('3.txt', 'r')

aa = a.read()
bb = b.read()
cc = c.read()

page = 'Content-type: text/html\n\n'
page += '<html>'
page += '<head><title>Survey Results</title></head>'
page += '<body>'
page += '<h1> Survey Results </h1>'
page += '1) Do you play an instrument: <br>'
page += 'Yes:' + str(aa.count('yes')) + '<br>'
page += 'No:' + str(aa.count('no')) + '<br> <br>'
page += '</body> </html>'
```

My permissions are correct as well, I am really confused as to what the problem is. Any kind of help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: do you return the content of page anywhere?

Comment: Yes, I have a print page at the end. Since I have cgitb.enable(), I usually get an error message if it's something within the code itself, but I get a 500 internal server error which doesn't give me any clues as to what the problem is.

Comment: Any alternatives to displaying the results in HTML are fine as well. As long as I get them to show up.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but do you actually print `page` anywhere? That snippet shows you constructing a string but not doing anything with it. Also, have you checked your webserver error log? Any unhandled exceptions would typically show up there.